# How can I count syscalls in a Go program on OS X?

Tags: c, go, system-calls

I'm trying to count the syscalls in my Go program on OS X Yosemite. I've tried using `dtruss` and `dtrace`, but both cause my program to crash with the following error, followed by a stack trace:

```
fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error
```

The two commands I've used are:

1. `sudo dtruss "./my_program my_arg"`
2. `sudo dtrace -c "powerset 2" -n 'syscall:::entry { @num[probefunc] = count(); }'`

### Things I've Tried

The main takeaway from my Google-foo has been to unset `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, which I have done numerous times to no avail.

`./my_program` is a binary that I created with `go install`. I've written an equivalent C program and both of the above commands work fine with that.

Comment: @JimB thanks, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use dtrace on macOS, you will need to use the external linker to build your program

```
-ldflags -linkmode=external
```